# Is it possible to change the date(year) in AMS subject classification number in a latex doc.?

Tags: amsart, datetime

I am creating a LaTeX doc. using `\documentclass{amsart}`. When I run it, the year appears in AMS subject classification is 1991. Is it possible to change it to 2010? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: A comment on an answer asked whether 2020 had been added yet, since the 2020 MSC has been released.  If you are submitting to the AMS, 2020 will be supported there, but a public update of `amsart` hasn't yet been released.  The AMS support group is taking the opportunity to see whether they want to make any other changes at this time.  Also, disruptions on account of the current COVID-19 pandemic affect this as well.  (Sent on behalf of the AMS technical group.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an optional argument to the `\subjclass` command, which you may specify to be `2010`.

```
\subjclass[2010]{Primary: 53C26}
```

Note that there are internal checks on the year, so the only valid values are `1991`, `2000` and `2010`.  Presumably this will be updated when the next subject classification is released for `2020`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\title{A title}
\author{A. Author}
\subjclass[2010]{Primary: 53C26}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

**update:** 
The `2020` option was added with version `[2020/05/29 v2.20.6]`.

Comment: to confirm -- it is definitely planned to add an option `[2020]` as soon as that version of the subject classification exists.  (work has already begun.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, any news on the 2020 option?

Comment: @Sigur -- I wish!  No word yet.  I'll inquire.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks for attention. I'm going to send a final version of a paper and I'd like to use it. Hopefully the editors will take care of it, specially because I used the 2020 msc.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, for a while, after reading the class file, I am using on preamble of my file the command `\@namedef{subjclassname@2020}{\textup{2020} Mathematics Subject Classification}` and it works well.

Comment: @Sigur -- Yup.  It's a really simple addition.  (I installed the previous two, though I wasn't responsible for the original code.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I tried to find the source on Git to make a pull request but I was not able. Any chances to have this soon in next update?

Comment: @Sigur -- Not on Git,  Only internal to AMS.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The 2020 option seems to be working now.

Comment: Omg, why is it needed to make an **update** for such a thing? Why does it not simply display *whatever* one writes inside the brackets?